# how to create dynamic linq query based on search criterias

Tags: c#, linq

I have a search form which i want to use to search a database for data. The searchbox has 4 checkboxes and 1 textfield. The problem is how do i build the linq query considering i dont know beforehand what textboxes the user will check for filtering the search. What i have so far is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult search(string ulv, string bjorn, string jerv, string gaupe)
{
    var query = (from o in db.observasjonene select o);
    if (ulv != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.art == ulv);
    }
    if (bjorn != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.art == bjorn);
    }
    if (jerv != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.art == jerv);
    }
    if (gaupe != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(o => o.art == gaupe);
    }
    IEnumerable ls = query.ToList();
    return Json(ls, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

The problem with the "where" clause is that if a condition is true, it overwrites the results from the earlier condition. I guess i need an "or" statement or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to check if `art` equals to any of provided values. You can combine those values into collection and check if collection contains `art` value:

```
var values = new [] { ulv, bjorn, jerv, game }.Where(v => v != null);
var query = from o in db.observasjonene
            where values.Contains(o.art)
            select o;
```

EF translates `Contains` into SQL IN operator.

Comment: What if we want also include substrings ? Ie o.art.Contains("jor");

Answer (score 1):

I'm using two approaches in this case:

**Build dynamic query:**

```
var q = DB.Invoices.AsQueryable();

if (isPresented != null)
    q = q.Where(iv => iv.IsPresented == isPresented);

if (ID != null)
    q = q.Where(iv => iv.ID == ID.Value);
    ...........................
return from iv in q 
orderby iv.DueDate descending 
select iv;
```

**Use Union to combine search results:**

```
var q1 = db.FeeInvoice.Where(fi => [QUERY1]));

 if (isPresented != null)
 {
     var q2 = db.FeeInvoice.Where(fi =>[QUERY2]));

     q1.Union(q2);
 }

 if (ID != null)
 {
     var q3 = db.FeeInvoice.Where(fi =>[QUERY3]);

     q1.Union(q3);
 }

...........................
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing all the parameters value to single column in the query ie. `art` *(see you have written same column name in each where condition)* . I'm not sure why are you doing so? you can simply take single parameter which compare the value like this

```
 public ActionResult search(string value)
 {
    query = query.Where(o => o.art == value);
 }
```

or if it is by mistake and you want to apply where condition along with multiple column then you can try something like this

```
query=query.Where(o => (o.art == ulv || ulv == string.Empty) && (o => o.bjorn == bjorn || bjorn=string.empty) && (o.jerv == jerv || jerv == string.Empty) && (o.gaupe == gaupe || gaupe == string.Empty));
```

Note: I assume your column name as your parameters name.